# Merge grid lines and axis in matplotlib 3D plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d, figure

I'm creating a simple 3D plot using matplolib like this (`python 3.7` `matplotlib 3.0`):

```
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def bilinear1(x,y):
    return (1-x)*(1-y)

fig = plt.figure()

ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')

x = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
y = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)

Z = bilinear1(X,Y)

ax.set_xticks([0, 1]);ax.set_yticks([0, 1]);ax.set_zticks([0, 1])
ax.set_xlim(0,1); ax.set_ylim(0,1); ax.set_zlim(0,1)
ax.set_xlabel('x'); ax.set_ylabel('y'); ax.set_zlabel('z')

ax.plot_surface(X,Y,Z, rstride=10, cstride=10)
```

This creates the following graph [image: graph]:

The plot is fine but it has the following problems:

- The are 2 grid lines in x=0 z=0, y=1 z=0 and x=0 y=1
- The axis lines are very close to the grid lines

I would like to only have one line on each of this places, producing a cleaner figure. I tried looking in the `Axes3D` methods, but I could not find anything.

Comment: So do you mean that you want, for instance, the y=1 and the z=0 lines to coincide? In this case look at the `ax.set_xlim()`, `ax.set_ylim()` and `ax.set_zlim()` methods.

Comment: @ThomasKühn I have already used those methods in the code, and I have given all the same values, nevertheless the lines arent coincident.

Answer (score 1):

I was also trying to solve this problem, and couldn't find a solution online.  Here is my solution:

There is an automatic padding at the edges or matplotlib 3d plots.  It seems to be exactly 1/50th of the axis range, so to use the gridlines as a nice box try something like this.

```
#Get the axis limits
xmin,xmax = axs.get_xlim()
ymin,ymax = axs.get_ylim()
zmin,zmax = axs.get_zlim()

#Find the amount of padding
xpad = (xmax-xmin)/50.0
ypad = (ymax-ymin)/50.0
zpad = (zmax-zmin)/50.0

#Set the ticks so they lay on top of eachother and make a nice box
axs.set_xticks((xmin-xpad,xmax+xpad)) 
axs.set_yticks((ymin-ypad,ymax+ypad))
axs.set_zticks((zmin-zpad,zmax+zpad))

#Change the labels to match the plot range
axs.set_xticklabels((xmin,xmax))
axs.set_yticklabels((ymin,ymax))
axs.set_zticklabels((zmin,zmax))
```